# How do I process each character in a string individually?

Tags: c

I am trying to run a word comparison program, but I can't stop the for loop from somehow adding to the character I am trying to compare.

```
for(m = 0; m < wordSize; ++m)
{
    a = l + m + 1;
    if(word[m] != message[a])
    {
        printf("Falsified by not word match: message[%d] = '%s' and '%s'\n", a, (char *)&message[a], (char *)&word[m]);
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

This gives me something like `Falsified by not word match: message[1] = ' a a a' and 'a'` if the message was `'a a a'` and the word matched was `'a'`.

Comment: What types are a, l, and m?  Also give a better example of what you are trying to solve.

Comment: your message starts with a space character, and it doesn't match your word 'a'. You may want to check your code for skipping white spaces! I'm not sure if I get your problem right!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `print()` and pass a string with `%s`, you will see everything inside the string until the end of the string.  The end of the string is marked with a "NUL" character, ASCII 0.  In C this is `\0`.

You are looking at characters, but then your error message is printing strings, and it is printing more than you want.

To make it just print the characters that were different, use the `%c` format code, like so:

```
printf("Falsified by not word match: message[%d] = '%c' and '%c'\n", a, message[a], word[m]);
```